# What is a non-gendered synonym for "macho"?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral, gender-politics

In teaching computer science, I often want to mention certain beliefs that would normally be described as "macho", such as "Strong types are for weak minds" (translation: only lousy programmers need a compiler that catches mistakes for them) or "Real programmer use assembly language".  You can see that attitude in these cartoons:

[image: UserFriendly]

I assume this inspired the following:

[image: xkcd cartoon]

How would you describe these programmers other than "macho"?  The closest terms I can think of are "tough", "reductionistic", and "masochistic", but none are quite right.  (FWIW, I teach at a women's college, and men are the coeds.)

Comment: Note that there aren't any non-gendered synonyms for testosterone, either.

Comment: I've heard the term *macha* used as a female counterpart to *macho*, but only as a joke, since it doesn't really translate into anything real.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Except an alternative spelling of [matcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matcha) …

Comment: Maybe, 'macho', since in English it means "having or characterized by machismo" and one assumes you want an English word, not a Spanish one.

Comment: I have a problem with the premise of this question. None of the example comics display anything close to "machismo" or macho behaviour, in fact I would call it the polar opposite. I would expect almost any of these speech bubbles to be the last thing someone says before being wedgied and stuffed into a locker. What they are displaying is attempting to be the "uber geek" or "alpha nerd".

Comment: @DigitalChris, I've lived so long among geeks that I'm used to this type of machismo.  I grant that's not how non-geeks would see these people.

Comment: Not sure this is communicative, but in my own mind, I think of them fundamentalists, by analogy to religious fundamentalists.  That is, they have their way, and their way is right because it is their way.  Note that it works both ways: certain programmers can be equally (if not more) fundamentalist about using certain tools, or forcing implementations into "high-level" languages, object or functional models, &c, even when objective measures show that other ways are better for the particular task.

Comment: Frankly, I'm generally shocked to hear "macho" and "programmer" in the same sentence.

Comment: You might find it helpful to step back from the term macho to begin with, and instead write out what parts of the behavior you're trying to highlight, and what type of a light you're trying to cast them in. The problem is that "macho" isn't inherently negative, depending on context. Many of the words that could be substituted here for macho are going to have definite negative or positive connotations (other than "hardcore" which sits in a nebulous space that can easily vary on surrounding contexts)

Comment: I'm with @DigitalChris 100% on this. The meaning sought by the body of this question is completely unrelated to "macho". Moreover, I would say asking for a "non-gendered synonym for macho" is something of an oxymoron. The concept of "macho" is inextricably interwoven with sexism and concepts of gender roles to the point that a word that's non-gendered would necessarily differ significantly in meaning.

Comment: @R..I'd say they are related, since "macho" is about saying my type is superior to the other type.  In that sense, all of the synonyms are about gender (defined not as sex but as type).

Comment: @DigitalChris: same tune, different chorus, IMO.  "Macho" sounds like a perfectly good description to me.  OP: "Macho" isn't as strongly gendered as all that.  I don't think people would misunderstand if you applied it to a woman, at least in this context.

Comment: This question make utterly no sense. There is no "non-gendered" version of macho. That's like asking for the non-gendered equivalent of feminine.

Comment: As a programmer, I hope you intend to strongly caution your students against these kinds of attitudes.  In that case, I don't see the problem with simply using the word *macho*.  I think the attitudes you're describing represent exactly the same kind of competitive posturing that characterizes machismo in other contexts.  And whether you believe these behaviors are innate or cultural, there's no denying that they're characteristically male.  So not only is *macho* the most accurate word to use, its gender association would add to the impact of your admonition.

Comment: espertus - that User Friendly cartoon is from 1999, XKCD is referencing it, not the other way around. @LegoStormtroopr If you read the entire question not just the title, you'd have seen that they weren't asking for a *direct* one-to-one synonym of 'macho', they were asking for a better word for a particular (non-gendered) phenomenon where 'macho' was the closest they could find.

Comment: Have you thought of "posturing"? As in "posturing ninny". Because honestly, these people know they are not being serious, they just want to get your attention, like little kids. I have a nephew, a grown man, who reckons Assembler is better than X in every situation. He's just posturing.

Comment: Should I change the question title?  I realize it's not accurate.

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't aware that "macho" was gendered in the first place.

Comment: @JoeZ A macho is by definition gendered, ergo, to ask for a non-gendered word for macho is simply silly. If you don't call it what it is, that's just a really bad kind of PCism.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In computer world, it seems like ***hardcore*** programmer is used in this sense and "Real programmer" phenomenon is compared to [No true Scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) fallacy. [However, hardcore programmer might be used in other senses as well.]

> The term Real Programmer in computer folklore has come to describe the archetypical "hardcore" programmer who eschews the modern languages and tools of the day in favour of more direct and efficient solutions—closer to the hardware. The alleged defining features of a "Real Programmer" are extremely subjective, differing with time and place, in the fashion of the "no true Scotsman" fallacy. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Programmers_Don%27t_Use_Pascal)

Definition of "[real programmer](http://www.th-soft.com/zzJargon/R.htm#Real_Programmer)" from "The New Hacker's Dictionary" by Eric S. Raymond:

> Real Programmer: [indirectly, from the book "Real Men Don't Eat Quiche"] n. A particular **sub-variety of hacker**: one possessed of a **flippant attitude toward complexity** that is **arrogant** even when justified by experience. The archetypal `Real Programmer' likes to program on the bare metal and is very good at same, remembers the binary opcodes for every machine he has ever programmed, thinks that HLLs are sissy, and uses a debugger to edit his code because full-screen editors are for wimps.

Related Dilbert comic strip:

[image]

Related readings:

- <sub>http://ronrecord.com/Mel.html</sub>
- <sub>http://blog.enfranchisedmind.com/2009/04/return-of-the-real-programmer/</sub>

---

It might be diverging from your context but:

In plain English, you can consider ***curt*** to emphasize a way of speaking that’s brief and blunt. It also has an added sense of being rude or rudely short.

A very similar word is ***brusque*** which can also be more general and describe the behavior.

> *curt:* rudely brief or abrupt, as in speech or manner [[TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/curt)
>
> *brusque:* talking or behaving in a very direct, brief, and unfriendly way [[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brusque)

An example of gender-politics situation from *[Price Waterhouse v. Hopkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_Waterhouse_v._Hopkins)* case (on the issue of employer liability for sex discrimination):

> [image]
>   [image]
>
> *The Gender Line: Men, Women, and the Law* By Nancy Levit

Comment: I would very much recommend "Hardcore" for this particular usage.  But not "curt" or "brusque", which more refers to a terseness, and not a proudness of using more difficult and rugged methodology.

Comment: @Zibbobz: Yes you are right. I was aware and mentioned that it diverges from the context. Also, being curt can be getting right to the point in a rude way. I might remove them if I come up with a better word.

Comment: I've worked at a STEM program where instructors and students used "hardcore" in a way very similar to what the OP describes, and I thought it worked very well.

Comment: If 'macho' isn't "non-gendered" then neither is 'hard-core'.

Comment: Note that the point of Nancy Levit's story is that words that _appear_ to be non-gendered can nevertheless have a gendered connotation in context.

Comment: I don't think *hardcore* has quite the same connotation as *macho*.  A hardcore programmer may be obstinate, but their expertise entitles them to be obstinate, whereas someone who is *macho* is merely posturing.

Comment: (And most programmers who express these kinds of attitudes *are* merely posturing, not entitled to them in the way that *hardcore* suggests.)

Comment: +1 for "hardcore", -1 for "curt/brusque".  This is why you should always post multiple answers as separate independent answers.

Comment: @endolith: Thanks endolith. I will consider your advice but I added a supporting context also.

Comment: The four terms are **real programmers**, **hardcore**, **old-school** or **die-hard**.  If you're **3l33t** you do all of that.  If you particularly make games and do all of that, you're **AAA** (said "triple-A"). Many comments on here simply don't understand the question - it relates to using "the hard way" "non-easy" programming techniques.  There's really no connection to "macho"-ness.

Comment: one more .. "badass" is popular, and means the same thing as the other four.

Answer (score 13):

In the particular context you give here, it’s not really about strength, but more about doing things in the most basic, unaided, original way possible. Considering we’re talking about developing computer code, this no-tech-help-allowed approach might properly be called *oxymoronic*, but a better term would, I think, be ***old-school*** (also written *old-skool* for humorous Internet effect):

> : typical of an earlier style or form : based on a way of doing things that was common in the past
>   : using or supporting traditional practices
>   [*(Merriam-Webster)*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old-school)
>
> A positive appellation referring to when things weren't flashy but empty of substance, were done by hard work, didn't pander to the lowest common denominator, and required real skill. Labour-saving devices, shortcuts that reduce quality and quitting before the task is done are not characteristics of "old school."
>   [*(Urban Dictionary)*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=old+school&defid=3126908)

This basic ‘feel’ of something can then be combined with some of the other suggestions already given here; the people in your comic strips can be described as ***competitively old-school*** or ***superciliously old-school***, for example.

Or if a noun is what you’re after, ***competitive/supercilious old-schooler*** works very well, too. Unlike *old-school* itself, which has shades of meanings that are not relevant here (as in the M-W quotes above), *old-schooler* to my knowledge has only the meaning relevant to the UD quote above.

Comment: +1, Janus, I like your spin on this, it didn't occur to me. Your take on this evokes connotations of Old Testament asceticism and zealotry.

Comment: old-skool is great

Answer (score 12):

I think I would suggest that these individuals are demonstrating ***one-upmanship***, or are perhaps ***purists*** or ***pedants***.

> **One-upmanship** is the art or practice of successively outdoing a competitor [...]  the systematic and conscious practice of "creative intimidation", making one's associates feel inferior and thereby gaining the status of being "one-up" on them [...]
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-upmanship)
>
> A **pedant** is a person who is excessively concerned with formalism, accuracy, and precision, or who makes an ostentatious and arrogant show of learning.
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedant)
>
> A **purist** is one who desires that an item remain true to its essence and free from adulterating or diluting influences. [...] According to the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary, the term dates from 1706 and is defined as "a person who adheres strictly and often excessively to a tradition" [...]
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purist)

Comment: +1 for one-upmanship. "Anything you can do, I can do better." "I used to walk 40 miles to school in the snow without shoes, uphill--both ways! And I liked it!"

Comment: @HunterHogan _You had snow? Luxury! When I was a kid I had to walk 40 miles to school through cow dung, and I had no legs._ +1 for one-upmanship.

Comment: This gets closest to the OP's question. One-upmanship encapsulates the competitive, but petty dispute over who is better or had it harder.

Comment: Purism and one-upmanship are good, but - sorry to be pedantic - pedantry is something else entirely. "Puritanical" is a good related adjective, implying both purism and a holier-than-thou attitude.

Comment: other than "purist" (which is sort of like "old-school" this really has naught to do with the question

Answer (score 6):

Other than hardcore (or maybe it should be "hardcore" in air quotes—and yes, these are both fairly specific to this context to carry a similar depth of meanings), I think the closest word you're going to find that tries to wrap in the multiple connotations of macho is going to be **vainglorious**.

This manages to encompass not only the sense of pompous egotism, but also still catching a hint that perhaps there is a degree of basis for it (probably not to the extent expressed), whether that's rightly or wrongly something to express pride in at all, or particularly to such a crass degree (which macho is usually assumed to do as well). It usually also attaches some of the bullheadedness that is assumed to go along with "macho," particularly with a sense of obstreperousness.

This is somewhat a tough one, because it really depends on what particular connotations you had intended to attach to "macho" in this context, and therefor which ones you wanted to keep in the replacement phrasing, since "macho" is easily so highly contextual in terms of final interpretation.

Comment: This good too.  I'd add a side helping of 'boastful' and maybe a taste of 'stretch the truth'.

Answer (score 4):

Popular question with many interesting answers. I am a recovering computer nerd, and I have worked in multiple professions that had similar battles of, "Oh yeah? Well, I can do the same thing but with my eyes closed."

A useful word for these people:

> **Pretentious**, adjective
>
> [Informal definition] : having or showing the unpleasant quality of people who want to be
>   regarded as more impressive, successful, or important than they really are
>
> 1 :  characterized by pretension: as
>
> a :  making usually unjustified or excessive claims (as of value or
>   standing)
>
> b :  expressive of affected, unwarranted, or exaggerated importance,
>   worth, or stature

--[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious)

My first computer (VIC 20) was so old that it did not have a hard drive: it had a tape drive for storing data and programs. Yes, I programmed in line-numbered Basic but that is irrelevant to important questions such as: can I accomplish the current task? Can I complete it on time? Will my work product be usable by others and modifiable by those who follow me?

Humans are social animals. Life is usually more similar to a relay footrace than to a solo footrace: the fastest person in the world is useless on a relay team if he or she cannot reliably receive or pass the baton.

Boasting about extreme competence in unnecessary skills is overvaluing those skills and attempting to inflate one's esteem: it is **pretentious**.

Comment: Oh yeah?  My first computer had punch cards.  And we punched them by hand, not with a keypunch machine :-)

Comment: @jamesqf so what? We had to make our own punchcards.  AND WE LIKED IT THAT WAY!

Comment: @Tony Ennis - that's it exactly!

Comment: Pretentious, and narcissistic, to boot (pun is optional).

Answer (score 3):

*[Die-hard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/die-hard)* programmer comes to mind:

> adjective
>
> : very determined or loyal;
>
> especially
>
> : very loyal to a set of beliefs and not willing to change those
>   beliefs

Of course, this phrase is particularly endearing if you have watched John McClane choose the hardest way to do every thing in every scene of every [Die Hard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YXi9JAgdf0) movie. *Yipee Ki Yay*, [Bruce Willis]!

Comment: fantastic suggestion

Answer (score 3):

There are some very good answers here, but I would add the followning for the case in question

**luddite**

**inverted snob**

Comment: My first thought was that "luddite" is wrong because these are technologists, but, by refusing to use the more modern technology, they are showing themselves to be a sort of luddite, traditionalist, or conservative, much as they would hate having those terms applied to them.

Comment: Yeah, @espertus - they're neo-pseudo-luddites!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than try for a replacement, I'd go with "macho (pause and smile) or macha, if you prefer". This establishes that you are aware of the connotations of folks who take machismo seriously, and are willing to have a little fun with such concerns, while at the same time acknowledging the parallels found in geek behavior.

And while several comments have decried the connection of the two concepts (is "geek machismo" an oxymoron?) there are connections. The sort of exchange typified by the cartoons in the OP do occur, although not quite as absurdly (which is what makes them funny. To those who *do* find them funny.) and represent a struggle for dominance, at least in the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

> **IMPERIOUS** *adjective*:
>
> assuming power or authority without justification; arrogant and domineering. "his *imperious* demands"
>
> *Synonyms*: peremptory, high-handed, commanding, imperial, overbearing, overweening, domineering, authoritarian, dictatorial, autocratic, authoritative, lordly, assertive, bossy, arrogant, haughty, presumptuous
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=imperious+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=imperious+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.1.6518463...........0.p2OCAnAco-U&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **or**, **possibly**:
>
> **SUPERCILIOUS** *adjective*:
>
> behaving or looking as though one thinks one is superior to others.
>   "a *supercilious* lady's maid"
>
> *Synonyms*: arrogant, haughty, conceited, disdainful, overbearing, pompous, condescending, superior, patronizing, imperious, proud, snobbish, snobby, smug, scornful, sneering
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=supercilious&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=supercilious+define&gs_l=hp..5.0l5j41.0.0.5.516641...........0.43GjE0jzQok&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **or maybe:**
>
> **ARCH-CONSERVATIVE** *adjective*:
>
> **1**. extremely averse to change and strongly adhering to traditional values.
>   "his social philosophy is *archconservative*"
>
> **ARCH-CONSERVATIVE** *noun*:
>
> **1**. a person who is extremely averse to change and strongly adheres to traditional values.
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=hss&oq=Arch-conservative&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=arch+conservative+definition&gs_l=hp..1.0j0i30l3j0i8i30.0.0.10.592980...........0.ohiXEEl74O4&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say that "macho" and in general badassery is a male trait anyway, which reminded me of a nice word for you:  Badass.

Comment: +1 for badass, although I'm not sure I agree with the generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful phrase to add to the list is [**all hat and no cattle**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle).  You would use this one for someone who brags a lot about their accomplishments, but doesn't have the actual skill and persistence to back it up.

As you might guess, the term originates from American (specifically Texan) [cattle rancher culture](http://ask.metafilter.com/8947/Whats-the-origin-of-all-hat-no-cattle#169661):

> ... it dates back roughly to the 1940s when Texas's traditional, agrarian, ranching economy was being tilted on its head by oilmen and an influx of Northeners (or just non-Texan Southerners, who don't necessarily get Texas either) to the Third Coast. These people may have owned ranches as part of a personal fortune but weren't ranchers in their blood, and many may have put on Texas affectations as an entertaining hobby of forced quaintness, which native Texans perceived as patronizing.

(It may also help to know that the stereotypical Texan cattle rancher wears a [large, distinctive hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_hat).)

Answer (score 2):

**Bro-grammer** is how I've heard this kind of (usually male) petty upsmanship braggartry  described. But it is an old game. See Monty Python's [Four Yorkshiremen Sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKHFZBUTA4k).

Comment: Ha, still gendered, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would describe the illustrated attitudes as ***competitive***. If you want to imply a somewhat more aggressive attitude, you might use ***cutthroat***.

A slang word that is associated with *macho* but is sometimes applied to both men and women is ***butch***.

Comment: I've only really associated 'butch' with women.

Comment: I would not recommend "butch", as it can be a very offensive word.

Comment: "Butch" is just a different word for "masculine".  And yes, in my experience, it's generally used to describe women -- more specifically, lesbians.  Most straight people, male and female, would probably take offense.

Comment: I really didn't want to reply to these comments, but consider [The Butch Factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Butch_Factor) as an example of the word applied to men. Although some may find it offensive if applied to them, it would only be bigotry that would lead them to do so. I would find it about as offensive as someone trying to imply I was Jewish (which would mean, I would not find it offensive at all).

Comment: @jxh: Note that even there, the word connotes gayness.  Regardless of whether you consider it bigoted or not, most guys don't like the implication.

Comment: @cHao: I specifically addressed the comments of the word not applying to men. The "connotation of gayness" is not applicable, since one would know if one were gay or not, so only the "masculinity" meaning remains. Just as when someone says to me "You are such a Jew with your money", it only means I treat my money carefully, since I am not Jewish.

Comment: @jxh: Frankly, your example is a really bad one.   It's offensive in pretty much the opposite way.  It has no meaning without racism -- in order to even interpret it, you have to bring in the stereotype of Jews as miserly.  Seems to me that that makes it patently racist, whether you're Jewish or not.

Comment: As for "butch", i've always seen its meaning as more along the lines of *oddly* masculine.  Either way, it's still gendered, so it doesn't fit.

Comment: @cHao: "Racist" is a pretty heavy word to toss at a simple example, which you had clearly understood in the way it was meant to be understood. Your understanding of how "butch" is used seems too narrow.

Comment: I only understood the example because i've heard what people say about Jews.  If i hadn't, i wouldn't know enough about racial prejudice to glean any meaning.  As for "butch", show me where is used in a way that doesn't imply to most people that the default is "unmanly".

Comment: @cHao: Understanding a stereotype does equate to being racist. The dictionary definitions indicate a usage where a man is overly manly.

Comment: *Understanding* a stereotype, not so much.  Incorporating it into your own speech?  Yes, in fact, i'd say one would have to (consciously or not) be a bit racist to invoke that stereotype in one's everyday speech.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butch_and_femme

Comment: @cHao I have only had such an extended conversation about stereotypes with you. That entry is itself specifically about how the word is applied to women.

Comment: And that is a very common usage.  In fact, regardless of what a dictionary told you, the only usage i have ever seen in real life is specifically in describing women and gay men.

Comment: As for the conversation, perhaps you should have it more often.  It pays to be aware of the different filters through which other people will view your words.  For example, ask a Jew how he feels about your example.

Comment: @cHao I am an ethnic minority that was born and raised in the American Midwest. I surmise my attitude is due to having a much more tolerant attitude towards colorful language. *Butch* included.

Comment: I surmise it's due to a relative lack of contact with other people who'd call you out for it.  Have to say i'm a bit surprised, though -- i would have thought if you went around the Midwest calling every guy you met "butch", you wouldn't survive to tell us how it went.  It's that offensive to some people, largely because of the link to gay/lesbian culture.

Comment: @cHao I seem to have hit some kind of nerve on you, so I will not respond beyond this. I was raised to believe in the good of people, but you seem intent on believing the worst about me. I try to conduct myself in a way where it is clear I mean no offense, regardless of the words I choose. If my words offend, I explain my intent, and that usually settles it. When listening to others, I apply the golden rule: I try to differentiate the intent and react accordingly.

Comment: @jxh: It's not that i believe the worst -- if i did, i'd think you were trying to offend.  It just seems like you're not giving due weight to how some arbitrary person will interpret your words.  Those other meanings are at least as important as the one you intended, It takes time to correct them, and other people aren't necessarily applying the "golden rule".  If you're not careful, you might not live long enough to explain to that rabid homophobe that you didn't just call him gay.

Comment: @cHao: I guess I refuse to believe that I live in a society where a hearing a comment is enough to trigger a kill response.

Comment: @jxh: Believe what you want, but [words _can_ get you killed](http://www.prisonplanet.com/cop-kills-unarmed-man-after-sarcastic-remark.html). All else being equal, it's better to err on the side of not offending people.

Comment: @cHao: Of course, I know that taunting a person wielding deadly force against you is unwise. However, I also prefer to not live in fear. You are free to live how you want. I know I do not intentionally go out of my way to hurt people's feelings. This usually results in amicable verbal transactions.

Answer (score 1):

[**Impudent**](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=impudent&use1828=on) describes the actual behavior.

> Impudent, a. [L. impudens.] Shameless; wanting modesty; bold with contempt of others; saucy.

So more figuratively [**Brazen**](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=brazen&use1828=on):

> 1. Pertaining to brass; proceeding from brass; as a brazen din.
> 2. Impudent; having a front like brass.

The metallic qualities could also be considered things like hard or tough.

Also since you evidently have a sense of humor, [mulet](http://www.mulletjunky.com/femullets.htm) [fish](http://chefdepaprika.com/2013/01/mullet-stuffed-pomegranate-sauteed-okra-fish-recipe/). [See Webster's Revised Unabridged, 1913 entry for [Macho](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=macho&use1913=on).]

Impudent and Brazen pulled from [Noah Webster's American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/macho), (1828): Examples omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You've already suggested *strong*, but there's also **no-nonsense**.

Comment: Yes, although I do think the reductionist prejudice they show is somewhat nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

What about "hacker" as in the original use of the term, not it's current usage which is conflated with "cracker"?

Comment: Not really—you can be a "Lisp hacker" or even "Python hacker". Hacker usually refers to someone with a heavily customized environment, and occasionally (but only occasionally) refers to a Real Programmer.

Comment: Which 'cracker'? A safe (or code) cracker or white trash?

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a neologism: nerdolympic.

I do like supercilious above, too. One-upmanship, also, although I don't know what the adjecvtival form of that is. "Arrogant" falls somewhere in the right ballpark, but it needs some sort of qualifier, as that nerd arrogance is not your garden variety arrogance, it's its own special thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if I understand your question entirely but in simple language would words such as: Be Firm; Steadfast or Immovable, suffice your needs? These can be used for both genders and can be spoken for motivational purposes especially in teaching values. I have heard them myself in different scenarios with positive effects coming from them, for either male or female listeners.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for words with a neutral or negative connotation.  I don't want to glorify the superciliousness/prejudice displayed by such programmers.